# Using BackboneJs with jQuery Deferreds

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I am using a technique I read about from [Sam Breed](http://quickleft.com/blog/leveraging-deferreds-in-backbone-js) for using Deferreds inside of Backbone.

Inside my `initialize` method of my Backbone `View` I have the following:

```
var me = this;

this.deferredTemplate = $.ajax({
    url: 'details/welcomeMaster.htm'
}).done(function (data) {
    me.template = data;
});
```

This will load a template file for me that is located externally to my `View`.

Then when I need it here is the code to new it up.

```
var something = new Dashboard.Views.WelcomeMasterView({
        collection: me.collection,
        el: $('.contentContainer')
});

something.deferredTemplate.done(function (data) {
        something.render();
});
```

Unfortunately I have to break up those 2 statements so that `something` is my Backbone `View` and not the jqXHR object. Other than that this code works just fine.

**Question**
Any ideas on how to chain together the 2 calls above? Inside the `.done()` method I need the Backbone `View` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you want to keep it simple you might prefer to first load the templates, then construct any views once you have fetched them. This is say how things work with AMD loaders providing the same thing.

Otherwise, one idea would be to add a `_render` that would do what your `render` normally does, say

```
_render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
},
```

Then, your normal `render` would call `_render` when ready:

```
render: function () {
    this.deferredTemplate.done(this._render);
    return this;  
},
```

This would keep things simple and you can go on calling `render()` the same way you always do. Note however the drawback: If you rely on having actually rendered after a call to render (say for instance you manipulate the `$el` somewhere else), you might not actually have the element there.

As a side note, while deferreds are a perfect fit for Backbone, their usage in the blog post you link to is unnecessary. A simple bind to `change` would have accomplished the same task in a cleaner way.

Comment: You might also find these articles I wrote to be useful: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/09/asynchronously-load-html-templates-for-backbone-views/ and http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/20/trafficcop-a-jquery-plugin-to-limit-ajax-requests-for-a-resource/

Comment: @DerickBailey You seem to have written an article for every Backbone question on stackoverflow ;) I need to go through your blog!

Comment: where do you think half of my article ideas come from? "... 5th time i've seen this question. i should write an article." :D

Comment: Thanks guys, this ended up being exactly how i solved it before even looking on here :)

Comment: @MikeFielden sorry meant the reset event the collection will fire upon fetch. See http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset